# SUMIFS formula amendment to search for 2 text options

Tags: sumifs

I currently have formula reading:
=SUMIFS('Data'!$AL:$AL,'Data'!$A:$A,'Reporting (Month)'!$F5,'Data'!$AA:$AA,"*Term Assurance*",'Data'!$AG:$AG,"<="&'Reporting (Month)'!$J$2,'Data'!$AG:$AG,"<>0")

I need to change it within the condition that is looking for items containing "Term Assurance" (there is * before and after the phrase but not showing when I post the question within the actual formula above) to now search for items (in the same location parameter) containing "Term Assurance" or "Over 50s".

Any idea how the above formula can be modified to add search for additional phrase?

I'm expecting for the formula to retain all current criteria with addition of one more word search for "Over 50s" within the current search area of column AA in Data tab